# Google Sheet Vlookup is not working right with nested function

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm having trouble trying to run a `VLOOKUP` query in Google Sheets. I'm trying to see if a value already exists in a given column. However, I need to sanitize the inputs since the provided numbers have 9 digits, and the inputs have 12. For example,

- Cell A1 - Given Value - `123456789`
- Cell B1 - Inputs --------- `999123456789`

I get the needed value from the input using the `RIGHT` Function taking the last 9 values

- Cell C1 - `=RIGHT(B1,9)`

Then run the `VLOOKUP` function

- Cell D1 - `=VLOOKUP(C1,B:B,1,0)`

The result in get in Cell D1 is:

> N/A. The error I get is "Did not find 123456789 in the VLOOKUP evaluation"

[image: VLOOKUP Error]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here since this formula works correctly in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that `RIGHT` converts number to text string

the solution is:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1*1, A1, 1, 0)
```

and here you can see what's going on:

[image]

or directly:

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(B1, 9)*1, A1, 1, 0)
```

but if you just want to check if partial number is present in full number you can do:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1&"", A1&"")
```

and ArrayFormula of that would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B&"", A1&""), "no"), ))
```

Comment: Thank you very much player0! That solves it. I was under the assumption that the cells are text-only.